# Cómo cambiar los estilos de cursor de todos los elementos de la página por una imagen personalizada

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, mouse

Buen día a todos. Estoy intentando cambiar el estilo del cursor del ratón en mi página web.
La cosa es que estoy tratando de que no solo se cambie el cursor por una imagen personalizada única, sino que si vas a tocar (click, hover) un enlace o algo por el estilo el cursor cambie a "Pointer" pero que éste también esté personalizado.
La idea sería que esto sea de forma automática para toda la página, es decir, sin tener que estar poniendo "cursor: url("personalizado.png"), default" y "cursor: url("pointer.png"), pointer" en cada uno de los elementos de la página.
Gracias por la ayuda <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no tener que tocar cada elemento de la página lo suyo es usar estilos CSS.
Por ejemplo si quieres un cursor para todo el body y una para el hover en las imágenes

```
body{
cursor: url(/global.jpg), auto
}
img: hover {
cursor: url(/imags.gif), auto 
}
```

Es decir defines el cursor para cada **tipo de elemento** en una sección **style** de la página o en un archivo css. En estos ejemplos pongo auto, pero lógicamente puedes poner el tipo que desees: poiinter, help, resize...
Como es natural si queires particularizar algún elemento usas las clases.
Espero que te sirva